# How do I place thumbnails from videos in a views slideshow?

Tags: files, views

If the user doesn't give a thumbnail for the video in the slide show, I would like to generate a thumbnail from the video. I looked through questions and couldn't quite find what I was looking for. I am using Drupal 7. I am using the views slideshow module.

Comment: what module are you using for the video field?

Comment: create an image field and force them to insert an image

Comment: I am using the Media module. I thought of forcing them to give an image, but I wanted the functionality of having an image from the video. I had it working before, I just don't know how to fix it. If you know of a tutorial that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that a few boxes were unchecked that I didn't know about.  This link shows a good tutorial on this: http://webwash.net/tutorials/display-video-thumbnails-media-module